# Why does this code yield an error with regards to the pow function?

Tags: c, macos, math, gcc, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int exp_for_level(int n) {
    return (int)(100 * pow(n, 2.3));
}

int main(){
    int x;
    x = exp_for_level(6);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I receive the following error when I run this code on an ***online compiler***

```
/tmp/cc28S7ML.o: In function exp_for_level':
main.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I rectify this?

After I couldn't get it to work on the online compiler, I followed advice from some other threads on 
The file is stored under a file grades.c on my mac
I've tried entering this

```
$ gcc - Wall - lm -o grades grade . c
```

into my terminal and i just get `zsh error: command not found`

Any ideas on what the issue is here too?
The online compiler I'm using is 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

EDIT: in my post, in main I'd miswritten the function as exp_to_level instead of exp_for_level. Didn't copy paste the entire code as it's too long. I narrowed it down and retyped it to the portion that yields the error.

Comment: Order matters, put `-lm` at the very end

Comment: Can you copy/paste the actual code? Since this doesn't compile for other reasons.

Comment: The spaces in `- Wall` and `- lm` won't help

Comment: Which online compiler exactly?

Comment: We're still waiting for you to tell us which online debugger you're using. And your source code is still bogous, an `int` is missing before `x`. You can [edit] your question. And did you retype your code here? Why didn't you copy/paste it?

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors in your code, you have defined a function `exp_for_level` but you use `exp_to_level`.

Then your `x` variable is not defined

If you fix your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int exp_for_level(int n) {
    return (int)(100 * pow(n, 2.3));
}

int main(){
    int x = exp_for_level(6);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

and you compile:

```
gcc -Wall powtest.c -o powtest -lm
```

it works.

About the error on the **online compiler**:

The `undefined reference` error occurs because you are missing `-lm` linker option.

Edit the online compiler command clicking on `Project->Compile Options`:

[image: compile option]

About this problem on your local machine:

> After I couldn't get it to work on the online compiler, I followed
>   advice from some other threads on The file is stored under a file
>   grades.c on my mac I've tried entering this
>
> ```
> $ gcc - Wall - lm -o grades grade . c
> ```
>
> into my terminal and i just get zsh error: command not found

you don't have the compiler installed.

You should install `clang`, Have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323367/compiling-c-source-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your function name is wrong in the main take a look here `exp_for_level`
 and in main its `exp_to_level` change one of them then also add `int x` in main to solve the issue.